# Subversion on Windows Server 2008

Tags: svn, version-control

(I'm Subversion noob) and we are planning to set up a single Subversion repository into a Windows Server 2008 (Terminal Server). We're have many client computers under the same domain. How to access this single repository? Should we install TortoiseSVN to these client computers? Can TortoiseSVN access easily this single repository (located in UNC path)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should we install TortoiseSVN to these client computers?

Probably yes - you'll need some Subversion client running.

> Can TortoiseSVN access easily this single repository (located in UNC path)?

Have you considered installing a real subversion server like [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/)? It's brain-dead easy to set up, and might be more flexible and reliable than using a network share.

With a real server, you would access the repository through the http or https protocols,  locking issues would be guaranteed not to happen, and you could control read/write access.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean VisualSVN or VisualSVN Server?

Comment: @juur I mean the server. It's a wrapper around the native svn server binaries, and an Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the repository via HTTP(S) and TortoiseSVN seems to be the defacto client app for accessing Subversion repositories.  You should not use the UNC path to the folder structure holding the repository. I actually don't think that would even work but I've never tried.

You will need to setup users in Subversion for everyone who wants to connect to the repository. Visit [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) for a free install/Management console to help you manage your Subversion repositories, users and groups.